# Proto-Slavic ablaut type

Tags: slavic-languages

PS решти r**e**šti (to speak) full e-grade / рѣчь r**ě**čĭ  (a speech)  lengthened ē-grade
PS **ĭ** PIE i may also be lengthened to PS **i** PIE ey
But what type of ablaut is бьрати b**ĭ**rati (to gather) / берѫ b**e**rǫ (I gather)?

Comment: Wiktionary says "From Proto-Balto-Slavic *bírāˀtei, from Proto-Indo-European *bʰéreti. The past stem *bьr-a- emerged from zero-grade *br-a- through secondary ablaut." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/b%D1%8Crati